# chef: How do I increase the CommandTimout for Mixlib::ShellOut in a ruby block?

Tags: chef, ruby

I'm trying to perform a database data load in a chef recipe on an Ubuntu 14.04 system with a Chef 11.10.4 based client.  I'm doing the data load in a ruby block and here are the relevant portions of the error in the log:

> Mixlib::ShellOut::CommandTimeout
>
> Command timed out after 600s:
>
> Command exceeded allowed execution time, killed by TERM signal.
>
> [2015-10-06T01:24:00+00:00] ERROR: ruby_block[Load Dataset] (chef-virtuoso::load line 178) had an error:
> Mixlib::ShellOut::CommandTimeout: Command timed out after 600s:

Anyone know how to increase the default CommandTimeout to 3600 for a `shell_out!` in a ruby block?

Here is the ruby block from the recipe that is failing:

```
::Chef::Recipe.send(:include, Chef::Mixin::ShellOut)

ruby_block "Load Dataset" do
  block do
    shell_out!(DATA_LOAD_COMMAND)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`shell_out!` takes an optional second parameter hash which may specify a timeout :

```
shell_out!(DATA_LOAD_COMMAND, timeout: 7200)
```

That being said, based on your example it really doesn't look like you need to use a `ruby_block` resource and would likely benefit more from either a `script` or `execute` resource instead.

Both of those support a timeout resource property which would do the same thing. You'll find additional documentation on the `execute` resource in the official docs : https://docs.chef.io/resource_execute.html